# Is Callout in a trigger always execute at the last, as sent email?

Tags: trigger, callout

I have a callout in after trigger use asynchronous method,
If Error happens in trigger execution, I want to cancel the Callout.
Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't callout in a trigger. If you try, you'll get an exception. The error is "Callout from triggers are currently not supported." You must make any callouts in a Visualforce page or asynchronous methods. You can't "cancel" a callout anyways. The API pauses the Apex Code until the callout completes.

If you're calling an asynchronous method, the method call occurs after the trigger completes successfully. If the call does not complete successfully, the asynchronous method will never be called. Basically, on an error, the transaction is re-wound back to the beginning of the DML operation and retried minus any errors (if allOrNone is false). Only asynchronous calls that survive a DML operation with no errors will be called.